# Is it safe and norm to put Google_client object in session?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-client

Is it safe to create `google_client` object and store it in `$_SESSION` variable.

Can we then use same google_client object from `$_SESSION` variable on multiple pages to do google stuff. Or, do I have to make new client on every page?

Most of the tutorial or example on internet use only one page, how to use `google_client` on multiple pages is what I trying to figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep creating it, but all the auth process and rest of the CLIENT_ID and other important information can be stored in variables for future use. Just instance it every page, re-auth with refresh token with every page change and you're good to go. Also you could do a specific GoogleConnection.php header kind of style and stop worrying of having it to type it every time you add a new page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your approach to the problem you're facing could be replaced with a different implementation pattern.

It sounds like your just trying to create the Google_Client object once, and have it persist throughout the application; probably to minimize the need to refactor code.  I would recommend you find an appropriate location in your code, that's hit on every page load, and instantiate the object there.

If you're using a framework, it's very likely you can hook into a Bootstrap mechanism.  If this is a custom build, then just find the most suitable centralized location you can.

But to answer your question, I would definitely not recommend putting your Google_Client object in a session variable.